# python time offset

Tags: python, time

How can I apply an offset on the current time in python?

In other terms, be able to get the current time minus x hours and/or minus  m minutes and/or minus  s secondes and/or minus  ms milliseconds

for instance

```
curent time = 18:26:00.000

offset = 01:10:00.000

=>resulting time = 17:16:00.000
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use a [`datetime.datetime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), then add or subtract [`datetime.timedelta()` instances](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t - datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=10)
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 26, 17, 18, 52, 167840)
```

`timedelta()` arithmetic is not supported for `datetime.time()` objects; if you need to use offsets from an existing `datetime.time()` object, just use `datetime.datetime.combine()` to form a `datetime.datetime()` instance, do your calculations, and 'extract' the time again with the `.time()` method:

```
>>> t = datetime.time(1, 2)
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 26, 1, 2)
>>> dt -= datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
>>> dt.time()
datetime.time(20, 2)
```

Comment: hum ok I was trying with a time object, it seems datetime is better for what i want thanks

Comment: I think now (python 3.5) it is dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.today(), t)

Comment: @NMO: you can pass in either a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` object as the first argument. This hasn't changed from the first release of the module. The code in your comment can't work however, as `datetime` can't both be the module and the class. `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), t)` works the same way `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t)` works.